# Is Backpropagation okay for this or should i try another approach?

Tags: networking, backpropagation

I'm making kind of "the life game" with some creatures and some food on a world. Creatures eat food in order to gain energy and when they have enough energy they reproduce. The energy that a food provides is based on the time that food has been on the world, the longer the better. I'm using a genetic algorithm for creatures but i want them to learn what's best through generations because the thing is i have 4 ways to search for food:

1.- The nearest one

2.- The one that provides more energy

3.- The one that provides the best % to mutate genes and gain some cool new things

4.- The one that represents the lower danger to reach

I have a neural network with an input of 100 genes, 4 hidden layers and 1 output layer which it's a vector with 4 components, each of them indicating the search option i should go with based on my genes.

Network is doing great with my initial input, but the thing is i want to keep feeding my network over generations so i can do things like for example creatures with LAZY genes evolved from searching the nearest food to the one that provides more energy so they can "do nothing" for longer periods of time (because yea, they're lazy).

Seems like i have to pass in all inputs everytime i train it, which is impossible because new inputs will generate over generations and i can't be training it with around 100 inputs every generation due to high cpu ussage.

My question: is back propagation okay for this particular case or should i use a different approach to do what i need?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Neural network takes around 20-60 seconds to converge and every crossover might occur once every 0.2 - 2 seconds. This is my first implementation.

Comment: Regarding your search options, you mention that units evolve from searching the nearest food to searching the one with more energy. Does that mean that your options 1-2-3-4 are sorted from worst to best option ? Should your units evolve so they learn to prioritize option 4 ? Also, do all creatures in population have identical gens?

Comment: No, there's not "better" search option. That's what i want my creatures to learn, what's the best search option based on environment, dangers around them, etc. Every creature has randomized genes at the beginning. After that it all depends on the fathers and mutation (which only happens 1% of the time)

Comment: A lot of your text is not related to the actual question so I'm not sure if I understood correctly but wouldn't your problem be solved by simply saving the weights of the network? Also, shouldn't *each* creature have it's own NN or are they supposed to have a hive-mind? It's not really surprising that this is computationally expensive, I'd parallize it and compute it on GPU. You might have a lower complexity evolving the neural network itself (i.e. its architecture!)

Comment: I'm actually trying that since yesterday and it's working good so far. I gave every creature a brain (NN) with random genes generated by GA. The thing is if i suddenly change the environment creatures wont evolve fast enough to survive. Probably a good solution may be incrementing the mutation chance on crossover but that will cause much more random creatures.